# How do I add the file in the controller in Codeignator?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am using Codeignator. My issue is, How do I add the file in the controller?

Let's explain in detail

I have code in the controller something like this below code. Just notice that if-else condition is twice.

```
foreach($order_list as $order) {
    if (is_array($order)) {
        foreach($order as $r) {
            if ($r - > status == -1) {
                //button
            } elseif($r - > status == 1) {
                //button
            } elseif($r - > status == 2) {
                //button
            } elseif($r - > status == 3) {
                //button 
            } else {
                //button
            }
            // It will increase more in future
        }
    } else {
        // same if-else code 
        if ($r - > status == -1) {//button}
        elseif($r - > status == 1) {//button}
        elseif($r - > status == 2) {//button}
        elseif($r - > status == 3) {//button }
        else {//button}
        // It will increase more in future
    }
}
```

So I thought, I will create a new file and add it something like this

```
foreach($order_list as $order) {
    if (is_array($order)) {
        foreach($order as $r) {
            //externalfile.php
        }
    } else {
       //externalfile.php
    }
}
```

**externalfile.php**

```
if ($r - > status == -1) {
    //button
} elseif($r - > status == 1) {
    //button
} elseif($r - > status == 2) {
    //button
} elseif($r - > status == 3) {
    //button
} else {
    //button
}
```

Why I am doing like this because I don't know to increase the number of lines and I don't want to change any condition or text or any HTML twice in the future.

Would you help me out or any other idea to solve this?

Actual code.

```
foreach($order_list as $order) { 
    if(is_array($order)){
        foreach($order as $r) {
            $encryption_id=base64_encode($this->encryption->encrypt($r->cust_id));
            $this->myCode($r);//added here
            $data[] = array(
                "Sr_No" => $n,
                "cust_id" =>$encryption_id,//encrpt the id 
                "Name"=>$r->c_firstname."".$r->c_lastname
            );
            $n++;
        }
    } else{
       $this->myCode($r);//added here
    }
}

public function myCode($status) {
    if ($status== -1) {
        $order_status='<a href="#">Action name</a>';
    } elseif($status == 0) {
        $order_status='<a href="#">Action name</a>';
    } elseif($status == 1) {
        $order_status='<a href="#">Action name</a>';
    } else {
        $order_status='<a href="#">Action name</a>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's best to add an another method to your controller

```
public function myCode($status) {

 if ($status == -1) {//button}
 elseif($status == 1) {//button}
 elseif($status == 2) {//button}
 elseif($status == 3) {//button }
 else {//button}
}
```

You should call it the following:

```
 $this->myCode($order_list);
```

for example:

```
foreach($order_list as $order) {
    if (is_array($order)) {
       foreach($order as $r) {
            $this->myCode($r);
            //some else
       }
    } else {
        $this->myCode($order);
    }
}
```

Comment: Give me some time to check this

Comment: my foreach is inside if (!is_array($order_list)) . Why you used outside can you explain me?

Comment: It does not matter. You wrote right. I think this is easier to understand. Did you check؟

Comment: I checked and got error " Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int". I am getting this error on the function myCode if condition.

Comment: please check it again with new modified answer

Comment: Give me time to check again

Comment: I just updated my code in the question. Please check it once. is it correct?

Comment: no. you must use $order in else. for example:
 else{
       $this->myCode($order);// replace $order with $r
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183838/discussion-between-user9437856-and-ali-sharifi).

Comment: The issue is in the $this->myCode($r); I have to write $this->myCode($r->status);

Comment: Yes, your answer helps me. Thanks